# Undesired complex number in the square root

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, complex, eigenvalues

I am trying to solve the eigenvalues of a hamiltonian
[image]

The code I used is typed below.

```
t = 0.1; 
h = {{0, (-t)*(1 + Exp[(-I)*ky]), 0}, {0, 0, (-t)*(1 + Exp[I*kx])}, {0, 0, 0}}; 
ham = h + Assuming[{Element[kx, Reals], Element[ky, Reals]}, Refine[ConjugateTranspose[h]]]; 
FullSimplify[Eigenvalues[ham], Assumptions -> Element[{kx, ky}, Reals]]
```

The `Eigenvalues` gives an undesired complex number (which should be elminated inside and outside the square root)

[image]

How can I elminate the undesired complex number?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try `PowerExpand` to simplify your last result.

Comment: Thanks! It works for me.

Comment: Fine, you're welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since symbolic calculations are better done with exact, rather than floating-point, numbers, the following was done with `t = 1/10`:

```
Eigenvalues[ham // ExpToTrig]
(*
  { 0,
   -Sqrt[2 + Cos[kx] + Cos[ky]]/(5 Sqrt[2]),
    Sqrt[2 + Cos[kx] + Cos[ky]]/(5 Sqrt[2])}
*)
```

Note: It will "work" with `t = 0.1` but the factor in the denominator gets incorporated as `Real` coefficients in the square root:

```
(*
  { 0,
   -Sqrt[0.04 + 0.02 Cos[kx] + 0.02 Cos[ky]],
    Sqrt[0.04 + 0.02 Cos[kx] + 0.02 Cos[ky]]}
*)
```

Thus rationalizing `0.1` is not necessary, but one should be aware that round-off error often leads to problems in symbolic manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

At least for this case, one can take an indirect route through `CharacteristicPolynomial[]`:

```
ham = Simplify[(# + ConjugateTranspose[#]) &[{{0, (-t)*(1 + Exp[(-I)*ky]), 0},
                                              {0, 0, (-t)*(1 + Exp[I*kx])},
                                              {0, 0, 0}}], {t, kx, ky} ∈ Reals]
   {{0, -(1 + E^(-I ky)) t, 0}, {-(1 + E^(I ky)) t, 0, -(1 + E^(I kx)) t},
    {0, -(1 + E^(-I kx)) t, 0}}

cp = FullSimplify[CharacteristicPolynomial[ham, λ], {t, kx, ky} ∈ Reals]
   λ (4 t^2 - λ^2 + 2 t^2 (Cos[kx] + Cos[ky]))

λ /. Solve[cp == 0, λ]
   {0, -Sqrt[2] t Sqrt[2 + Cos[kx] + Cos[ky]], Sqrt[2] t Sqrt[2 + Cos[kx] + Cos[ky]]}
```